# Sending data through esp8266 using arduino

Tags: esp8266, gps

I'm trying to send GPS data using esp8266 using Arduino board. I've used neo-6m receiver and esp8266-01 module. Below is my program using AT commands. The program is successfully compiled and loaded to the Arduino board, but the only output it gives on serial monitor is a simple begin. None of the AT commands are being executed. Not even the module connects to wi-fi. I can't point the error in my code. Please help me find the possible error. 
Thank you

```cpp
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

TinyGPSPlus gps;

String ssid = "JioFi_244DB1D";

String password = "q52fq74c9s";

SoftwareSerial esp(6,7);

SoftwareSerial ss(8,9);

char Lat[12], Lon[12], alt[12],ch;

byte NOS;

byte l;

String webpage;

void reset(){

  esp.println("AT+RST");

  delay(1000);

  if(esp.find("OK"))

    Serial.println("Module Reset");

    }    

    void ConnectWifi(){

      esp.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");

      esp.println("AT+CWMODE=1");

      String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\""+ssid+"\",\""+password+"\"";

      esp.println(cmd);

      delay(4000);

      if(esp.find("OK"))

      Serial.println("Connected!");

      else {

        ConnectWifi();

        Serial.println("Connecting..");

        }

      }

void setup(){

  esp.begin(9600);

  Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("begin");

  reset();

  ConnectWifi();

  esp.println("AT+CIFSR");

  while(esp.available()>0){ 

  if(esp.find("STAIP"))

  {Serial.println("IP Address:");

  while(esp.available()>0)

  {ch=esp.read();

  Serial.print(ch);}

  }}}

void loop() {

    ss.listen();

    delay(2000); 

    while(ss.available()>0)

    {

    gps.encode(ss.read());

    {

      if(gps.location.isValid()){

           // dtostrf(gps.location.lat(),1,6,Lat);

      //dtostrf(gps.location.lng(),1,6,Lon);

      webpage = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><form method = \"post\" action =\"http://localhost/php/esppost.php\"><label for = \"latitude\">Latitude:<\label><input type=number id = \"latitude\" name= \"latitude\" readonly value=";

        //                L = Lat.length();

      l= webpage.length();

      esp.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,");

      esp.print(9+l+5);

      esp.println(webpage);

      esp.print(gps.location.lat(),6);

      esp.print("\">");

      delay(500);

      webpage = "<Label for = \"Longitude\">Longitude:</Label><input type = \"number\" id = \"Longitude\" name = \"Longitude\" readonly value =\"";
      l=webpage.length();

      //L = Lon.length();

      esp.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,");

                        esp.print(9+l+5);

      esp.println(webpage);

      esp.print(gps.location.lng(),6);

      esp.print("\">");

      }

      else

      webpage="Location Invalid";

      l=webpage.length();

      esp.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,");

      esp.print(l+2); 

      esp.println(webpage);

      delay(500);

      if(gps.altitude.isValid()){

      dtostrf(gps.altitude.meters(),1,6,alt);

      webpage = "<label for=\"Altitude\">Altitude:<\label><input type = number id=\"Altitude\" name=\"Altitude\" readonly value=";

      l=webpage.length();

      //L= alt.length();

      esp.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,");

      esp.print(9+l+2);

      esp.println(webpage);

      esp.print(gps.altitude.meters(),6);

      esp.print("\">");

      }

     if(gps.satellites.isValid()){

        NOS= gps.satellites.value();

        webpage= "<lable for = \"NOS \"> Number of Satellites:<\label><input type=number id=NOS name= NOS readonly value =";

        l= webpage.length();

        esp.println("AT+CIPSEND=0,");

        esp.print(2+l+22);

        esp.println(webpage);

        esp.print(gps.satellites.value());

        esp.print("></body></html>");

        delay(500);


     }}

    esp.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");

      }    
}
```

Comment: ?do you have RX to TX for `esp`?

Comment: yes, m using the similar connections

Comment: write a minimal test sketch

Comment: thank you. I changed the baud rate to 115200 and now it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

SoftwareSerial can't listen on two instances. There is a `.listen()` function to switch between SoftwareSerial instances.

The esp8266 AT firmware doesn't wait until you listen on the SoftwareSerial instance. If there is a connection to the server it sends +IPD and data. If the SoftwareSerial instance doesn't listen the information about client connection is lost.

You must listen to esp8266 all the time, so you can't use two SoftwareSerial instances.

You could use the RX pin of Uno to receive data from GPS module over hardware Serial.

Comment: I've made some changes to my program. I connected GPS Tx to Rx of my UNO board, replaced ss with Serial and removed ss.listen(). but still m getting the same result as before. Can you please suggest me what's the error I m still doing?

Comment: @user3185742, did this answer help? which interface's baud rate did you change?